# LWUIT Event Handling

Tags: java-me

In a LWUIT form when I Command Listener and when I use Action Listener ,give me a example.In a lWUIT form how to go one from to another form when I click a Button.Please give me a code regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

command Lister is default j2me library class while ActionListner is lwuit class,

i reccomend to use `ActionListner` 
example

declare class as

see this example [Introduction_to_Lightweight_User_Interface_Toolkit](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Introduction_to_Lightweight_User_Interface_Toolkit)

**EDIT**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
  if(event.getSource() == nyButton){
    Form secondForm = new Form();
    secondForm.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: ,thanks for the suggestion,I am new in this technology,the link u given that's work properly,but I want to know how to write the code when I click the button and and open another Form,this ex is in same Form,when I click the Button the event occurred in same Form.